# I want to convert a variable for date with several repeats into a date format suitable that can plot in a time series using R

Tags: date, time-series, lubridate

I am wanting to convert the Quarter column into a date format in the data frame df1_long

```
Quarter        Country    value
 1: Q1-2019      Australia 1607.929
 2: Q2-2019      Australia 1267.899
 3: Q3-2019      Australia 1584.615
 4: Q4-2019      Australia 1627.014
 5: Q1-2020      Australia 2000.000
 6: Q3-2022      Australia 1960.000
 7: Q4-2022      Australia 1908.295
 8: Q1-2023      Australia 2200.000
 9: Q2-2023      Australia 1838.000
10: Q1-2019             US 3652.640
11: Q2-2019             US 3017.615
12: Q3-2019             US 3081.797
13: Q4-2019             US 3179.357
14: Q1-2020             US 4064.289
15: Q3-2022             US 3076.462
16: Q4-2022             US 3987.771
17: Q1-2023             US 4036.000
18: Q2-2023             US 3032.000
19: Q1-2019         Canada 3311.035
```

When I try `df1_long$Q1 <-as.Date(as.yearqtr(df1_long$Quarter, format = "Q%q-%y"))` using the lubridate library, I end up with so that all the years get defaulted to 2020.

```
 Quarter        Country    value         Q1
 1: Q1-2019      Australia 1607.929 2020-01-01
 2: Q2-2019      Australia 1267.899 2020-04-01
 3: Q3-2019      Australia 1584.615 2020-07-01
 4: Q4-2019      Australia 1627.014 2020-10-01
 5: Q1-2020      Australia 2000.000 2020-01-01
 6: Q3-2022      Australia 1960.000 2020-07-01
 7: Q4-2022      Australia 1908.295 2020-10-01
 8: Q1-2023      Australia 2200.000 2020-01-01
 9: Q2-2023      Australia 1838.000 2020-04-01
10: Q1-2019             US 3652.640 2020-01-01
11: Q2-2019             US 3017.615 2020-04-01
12: Q3-2019             US 3081.797 2020-07-01
13: Q4-2019             US 3179.357 2020-10-01
14: Q1-2020             US 4064.289 2020-01-01
15: Q3-2022             US 3076.462 2020-07-01
16: Q4-2022             US 3987.771 2020-10-01
17: Q1-2023             US 4036.000 2020-01-01
18: Q2-2023             US 3032.000 2020-04-01
19: Q1-2019         Canada 3311.035 2020-01-01
```

How can I can correct this?

I have tried lubridate as well as
`df1a_long <- df1_long %>% mutate(qtr = quarter(x, with_year = T))`
but this didn't work.
When other options were tried it would often come up with "Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" error that I think is due to there being more than one identical date appearing in the quarter as there are multiple countries being measured at the same timepoints.

Comment: as.yearqtr is from the zoo package, not lubridate

Comment: as.Date(as.yearqtr(df1_long$Quarter, format = "Q%q-%Y")) works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `%y` is for a year without a century (00–99). What you want is %Y, which is year with century (e.g. 2023).

You can read more information about date format strings in the R documentation [here](https://rdrr.io/r/base/strptime.html).